# Efficiently persist many slices referencing the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a list of DataFrames which are slices to another DataFrame. I'm looking for a way to efficiently persist the DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

timestamps = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2023-03-29", freq="H")
values = np.random.rand(len(timestamps))
score_df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": timestamps, "value": values}).set_index("timestamp")

referenced_frames = [
    score_df.iloc[score_df.index.slice_indexer(date, date + pd.Timedelta(days=1000))]
    for date in timestamps
]
```

When using pickle to persist the DataFrames many copies of the same data are created which cause a very large memory usage:

```
import pickle
# WARNING: this results in a large memory usage and file on disk
with open("test.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(referenced_frames, f)
```

I know I could simply persist the original DataFrame and the slices into it:

```
slices = [
    score_df.index.slice_indexer(date, date + pd.Timedelta(days=1000))
    for date in timestamps
]
```

However, that ends up being too slow for my usecase:

```
>>> %timeit referenced_frames[999]
21.9 ns ± 1.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit score_df.iloc[slices[999]]  # This is too slow
15.1 µs ± 420 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Is there a way to efficiently persist my data? I'm okay with using another data structure than a list, as long as I can access the data very efficiently.

Comment: You can't compare the two methods. What about the time you consume to build `referenced_frames`? (4s on my machine)

Comment: @Corralien The build time is not really relevant for my use, I only need to build it once, but I need to index millions of times. This is also a simplified example, with the real data building does not take 4 seconds but half an hour, which is exactly why I would like to persist the results.